# Cosmos DB stored procedure: I can query the DB, but when I try to upsert I get a 'not same partition' error

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I understand that stored procedures run in the scope of a single partition key.

It is also possible to do operations that change data, not just read it.

ID must be string, so I must roll my own autoincrementer for a separate property to use in documents.

I am trying to make a simple autoincrement number generator that runs in a single stored procedure.

I am partitioning data mimicking a file tree, using forward slashes to separate+concatenate significant bits that make my partition names. Like so:

/sometype/foo/bar/

/sometype/ids/

The first item is always the document type, and every document type will have a 'ids' sub-partition.

Instead of holding documents, the /sometype/ids/ partition will hold and reserve all numerical ids that have been created for this document type, for autoincrement purposes.

this satisfies uniqueness within a partition, stored procedure execution scope, and unique document count within a document type, which is good for my purposes.

I got stumped in a stored procedure where I want to get a specified id, or create it if it does not exist.

I can query my partition with the stored procedure, but the upsert throws an error, using the same partition key.

I designed my database with "pkey" as the name of the property that will holds my partition keys.

Here is the code:

```
//this stored procedure is always called from a partition of type /<sometype>/ids/ , where <sometype> os one of my document types.
//the /sometype/ids/ is a partition to reserve unique numerical ids, as Cosmos DB does not have a numerical increment out of the box, I am creating a facility for that. 
//the actual documents of /sometype/ will be subpartitioned as well for performance. 
function getId(opkey, n, id) {
// gets the requested number if available, or next one.
//opkey: string - a partition key of cosmos db of the object that is going to consume the generated ID, if known. must start with /<sometype>/ which is the same that is being used to call this SP
//n: integer - a numerical number for the autoincrement
//id = '' : string - a uuid of the document that is using this id, if known

if (opkey === undefined) throw new Error('opkey cannot be null. must be a string. must be a valid partition key on Cosmos DB.');
n = (n === undefined || n === null)?0:n;
id = (id === undefined || id === null)?'':id;

var collection = getContext().getCollection();
//make opkey parameter into an array
var split_pkey = opkey.split('/');
//recreate the pkey /<sometype>/ids/ because I can't find a reference to this string inside the context. 
var idpkey = '/'+split_pkey[1]+'/ids/'; 

//first query as SQL
//get highest numerical value.
var q = 'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM c \
WHERE c.pkey = \''+idpkey+'\' ORDER BY c.n desc';

//helper function to create uuids. can I ditch it?
function CreateUUID() {
    return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
        var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
        return v.toString(16);
    });
}

// Query documents and take 1st item.
var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
    collection.getSelfLink(),
q
,
function (firstError, feed, options) {
    if (firstError) throw "firstError:"+firstError;

    //console.log(collection.options.);
    console.log(idpkey+', '+n+', '+id+"-");
    var maxn = 0;
    // take 1st element from feed
    if (!feed || !feed.length) {
        //var response = getContext().getResponse();
        //response.setBody(null);
    }
    else {
        maxn = feed[0].n;
        //var response = getContext().getResponse();
        //var body = { original: '', document: '', feed: feed[0] };
        //response.setBody(JSON.stringify(body));
    }
    console.log(maxn);

    //query for existing numerical value
    q = 'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM c \
    WHERE c.pkey = \''+idpkey+'\' \
    AND \
    c.number = '+n+' \
    OR \
    c.id = \''+id+'\'';

    var isAccepted2 = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
    q
    ,
    function (secondFetchError, feed2, options2) {
        if (secondFetchError) throw "second error:"+secondFetchError;
        //if no numerical value found, create a new (autoincrement)
        if (!feed || !feed.length) {
            console.log("|"+idpkey);

            var uuid = CreateUUID();
            var newid = {
                    id:uuid,
                    pkey:idpkey,
                    doc_pkey:opkey,
                    n:maxn+1
                };
            //here I used the javascript query api
            //it throws an error claiming the primary key is different and I don't know why, I am using idpkey all the time
            var isAccepted3 = collection.upsertDocument(
                collection.getSelfLink(),
                newid
                ,
                function (upsertError,feed3,options3){
                    if (upsertError) throw "upsert error:"+upsertError;
                    //if (upsertError) console.log("upsert error:|"+idpkey+"|");
                    //var response = getContext().getResponse();
                    //response.setBody(feed[0]);
                });
            if (!isAccepted3) throw new Error('The third query was not accepted by the server.');
            
            console.log(" - "+uuid);
            
        }
        else {
            //if id found, return it
            //maxn = feed[0].n;
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody(feed[0]);
            //var body = { original: '', document: '', feed: feed[0] };
            //response.setBody(JSON.stringify(body));
        }
    });
    if (!isAccepted2) throw new Error('The second query was not accepted by the server.');
});
if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
```

}

The error message is :
"Requests originating from scripts cannot reference partition keys other than the one for which client request was submitted."

I don't understand why it thinks it is in error, as I am using the variable **idpkey** in all queries to hold the correct pkey.

Answer (score 0):

Talk about brain fart!
I was violating my own rules because I was misspelling the partition name in the request, making the first part of the partition key **/sometype/** different from the parameter sent, causing a mismatch between the execution scope's partition key and the **idpkey** variable, resulting in the error.